# Cannot import import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;

Tags: java, android

While learning about RecyclerView, I am facing some problem. GreenAdapter Class failed to import “android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView”. I am using Android Studio 3.1.4. My compile SDK Version is 28. Here's my build.gradle File:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28



    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.sunshine.sunshine.app"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"


    }

    buildTypes {
       release {
           minifyEnabled false
           proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
       }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':sunshinemodule')
    implementation project(':base')

    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-rc01'
}
```

I am also sharing the code where the import is not working:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add

```
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1' //28.0.0-rc01
```

After that, **`Clean-rebuild`** and **`Run`**.

Comment: It is showing that, "This support library should not use different version than compileSDK version". For the record my CompileSDK version is 28.

Comment: @RashedurRahman https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions

Comment: I have replaced the implementation line with following:
" implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0-rc02'"

But still the import issue is not fixed

Comment: I've added the dependency in the build.gradle of sunshine module and the issue is fixed. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your gradle:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0-rc01'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc01'
```

and then click "Sync now".

Answer (score 0):

Right click on app --> Open Module Settings --> Dependencies then on right side click on plus button. Add library dependency and search recyclerview and then add it.[image]

Comment: I've added the dependency in the build.gradle of sunshine module and the issue is fixed. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @RashedurRahman Please accept the answer if it is helpful for you :)